# JSF page conversion error

Tags: java, jsf, compiler-errors

I am getting an error message in my JSF pages... `Conversion error setting value 'delovenier' for 'null converter'`, where *delovenier* is the name of the chosen project.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Could someone please assist me.

This is my JSF code...

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="proj" value ="#{studentEController.gekozenProject}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{studentEController.projecten}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

And this is my code in the managedBean `StudentEController`.

```
private List<ProjectE> projecten;
private ProjectE gekozenProject;
```

As you can see, they have the same type of `ProjectE`.

Comment: Please post here whole bean class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data transferred between the server and the client will be in string form.

The Expression Language can coerce a set of standard types (ints, etc.), but for complex types you are going to have to add a [Converter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to your component. Your converter will serialize `ProjectE` types to strings at render time and deserialize them to new `ProjectE` instances when forms are submitted.

You can create converters for specific types or add them explicitly to components.

See [Creating a Custom Converter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html) in the Java EE 6 tutorial and the [`<f:converter>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/f/converter.html) tag.